# How to open file uploaded using file field

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am building a form which has a file upload field using which users can upload attachments. I want to provide a way for users to inspect the attachment they have attached before submitting the form. So, on clicking a button, whatever file has been selected using the file field should open in a new window. I have not been able to figure out how to provide data to the `window.open` call from the file field. The following does not work:

```
$("#view_attachment_btn").on( 'click', function() {    
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        window.open(fr.result);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL($("#file_upload_field").val());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the selected file using JS File API, you must use plain javascript :

`$("#file_upload_field").val()` will return `C:/fakepath/xxx`

You must fetch the JS object using `get(0)`, only then you can access the actual selected file using `.files` attribute, which will return an array of selected files. Append `[0]` to fetch the first selected file.

```
$("#view_attachment_btn").on( 'click', function() {    
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        window.open(fr.result);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL($("#file_upload_field").get(0).files[0]);
}
```